# Is it possible to limit the number of calls to the cons function in the duplicate() function?

Tags: list, duplicates, lisp, common-lisp, cons

I wrote  the function `double()` that  duplicate the items in a list as follows:

```
(defun duplicate (l)
    (if (null l) nil
        (cons (car l) (cons (car l) ( duplicate (cdr l))))))
```

The `duplicate()` function  make two calls to the `CONS` function  for each item in a list:

```
Break 1 [2]> (trace cons)
;; Traçage de la fonction CONS.
(CONS)

Break 1 [2]> ( duplicate '(1 2 3))
1. Trace: (CONS '3 'NIL)
1. Trace: CONS ==> (3)
1. Trace: (CONS '3 '(3))
1. Trace: CONS ==> (3 3)
1. Trace: (CONS '2 '(3 3))
1. Trace: CONS ==> (2 3 3)
1. Trace: (CONS '2 '(2 3 3))
1. Trace: CONS ==> (2 2 3 3)
1. Trace: (CONS '1 '(2 2 3 3))
1. Trace: CONS ==> (1 2 2 3 3)
1. Trace: (CONS '1 '(1 2 2 3 3))
1. Trace: CONS ==> (1 1 2 2 3 3)
(1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

Is it possible to limit the number of calls to the `CONS` function to one per each list item?

Comment: Ultimately, no, because `cons` adds only one item to a list, and you are adding two items at each step.

Comment: And we can't combine the `cons` function with lisp mapping function to get this resolved?

Comment: I think that depends on whether your implementation has any optimizations for concatenating two lists. Conceptually (I think), anything that builds a new list does so by adding one element at a time to the front of an arbitrarily long list.

Comment: If you're willing to destructively modify the old list,  sure.  But the key to thinking about this is to realize that a cons is a node in the list.  For a list with 2n nodes, you need 2n cons cells.  If you're literally worried about explicit calls to the CONS function,  use LIST* instead:  `(list* (car l) (car l) (duplicate  (cdr l)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, for the same reason you cannot fill a 10 liter bucket using 5 liters of water.

A list of 10 elements requires 10 cons cells.

Comment: Thank you for your help . Your comments confirm my opinion

Answer (score 0):

A destructive version would make that possible:

```
(defun duplicate (l)
  (if (null l)
      nil
    (destructuring-bind (f . r)
        l
      (setf (cdr l)
            (cons f (duplicate r)))
      l)))

CL-USER 10 > (duplicate (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate all the cons calls:

`(list* (car l) (car l) (duplicate (cdr l)))`

Comment: How can you be sure `list*` won't be calling `cons` in any implementations of Common Lisp?

Comment: To a degree I was being facetious, but I also thought possibly the OP was looking more for a way to avoid *coding* two cons calls so offered the nicer `list*` syntax. But looking back I see `trace` being taken as the source of truth so my crystal ball likely failed me.